# How to show the data that retrieved from the Firestore in reverse order in a recyclerView in Kotlin Android?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following code to show the data in `recyclerView` that I retrieve from `firestore`.
What I am trying to do is, show the data in `recyclerView` in the reverse order of the data I get from Firestore.

```
    fun populateOrdersListInUI(ordersList: ArrayList<Order>) {

    hideProgressDialog()

    if (ordersList.size > 0) {

        rv_my_order_items.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        tv_no_orders_found.visibility = View.GONE

        rv_my_order_items.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        rv_my_order_items.setHasFixedSize(true)

        val myOrdersAdapter = MyOrdersListAdapter(requireActivity(), ordersList)
        rv_my_order_items.adapter = myOrdersAdapter
    } else {
        rv_my_order_items.visibility = View.GONE
        tv_no_orders_found.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Eidt:

[image]

Edit: Added `xml` code.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorOffWhite"
    tools:context=".ui.fragments.OrdersFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_my_order_items"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the Query that you perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a reversed Arraylist before you submit it to your adapter.

```
val reversedArray = ArrayList(ordersList.reversed())
val myOrdersAdapter = MyOrdersListAdapter(requireActivity(), reversedArray)
```

You can also reverse the ArrayList without creating a new one

```
ordersList.reverse()
val myOrdersAdapter = MyOrdersListAdapter(requireActivity(), ordersList)
```

Comment: I have updated my question with a screenshot of an error. Can you check it?

Comment: edited the answer, you need to tell explicit that you are creating an arraylist, because by default reversed returns a List. Also added a 2nd method to reverse your list

Comment: Which option is better when it comes to performance, first or second? A minor change is required, change 'reversedArray' from 'ordersList'. I can accept this as the answer as it's working perfectly after making the change.

Comment: The first one creates a new array, every changes done to the original Array need to be passed down to the copied array to make changes to the recyclerview.
The second one alters the original array, changes to the array will directly effect the recyclerview.
Creating both lists takes O(n) time, but the first one needs more memory, because you got 2 arrays now. The original one and the altered copy

Comment: Can you take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/68122591/13935956

Answer (score 1):

Try using this [constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/LinearLayoutManager#LinearLayoutManager(android.content.Context,%20int,%20boolean)) of LinearLayoutManager while setting reverseLayout to true like

```
rv_my_order_items.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true)
```

if it is a vertical and HORIZONTAL for horizontal orientation. This way you won't have to keep on reversing and adding list if you choose to add data to your arraylist

Comment: There is a small problem. It leaves some blank space at the top when I have fewer items. How can I solve that?

Comment: I assume your recycler view is set to `match_parent` try using `wrap_content` since using `match_parent` will result in the behaviour you are describing.

Comment: I tried changing the `layout_height` of the `recyclerView` to `wrap_content`. When I have a few items, it leaves some blank space at the top and bottom, it's like the `recyclerView` is centered (there is no gravity set). Then I tried changing the `layout_height` of the `ConstraintLayout` to `wrap_content`. It worked when I have a few items. But,...

Comment: ...when I have more items, `recyclerView` is scrolled down to the last item. If there is no other way to start from the first item in the `recyclerView` then this solution doesn't really serve the purpose. I have updated my question with `xml` code. I only played with the heights of the `recyclerView` and the `ConstrainLayout`. Rest everything remains the same.

Comment: Try using `setStackFromBottom(true)` and `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0)` also remove the bottom constraint of recycler view to prevent it from being centered