# How to filter data before adding it to the recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am pulling some data from the `firestore` and after that, I want to filter it before adding it to the `recyclerView`. Is that possible?
The data that I have pulled is an `ArrayList` which has a field called 'order_status'. It may contain many different statuses, but I want to filter it out so that I will be left with only "Pending", "Order Received", "In Process", "Packed".

The following code is used to pull the data from the `firestore`

```
   fun getOrderStatusList(fragment: OrdersByStatusFragment) {

        mFireStore.collection("orders")
            .whereIn(
                "address.pinCode",
                listOf("676767", "652365","679577")
            )    
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                val list: ArrayList<OrderStatus> = ArrayList()

                for (i in document.documents) {

                    val orderStatus = i.toObject(OrderStatus::class.java)!!
                    orderStatus.id = i.id

                    list.add(orderStatus)
                }

                fragment.successOrderStatusList(list)

            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                fragment.hideProgressDialog()
            }
    }
```

The following code is part of the fragment.

```
    fun successOrderStatusList(orderStatusList: ArrayList<OrderStatus>) {

    hideProgressDialog()

    if (orderStatusList.size > 0) {

        rv_order_by_status.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        tv_no_orders_by_status_found.visibility = View.GONE


        rv_order_by_status.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        rv_order_by_status.setHasFixedSize(true)

        val orderStatusListAdapter =
            OrderStatusListAdapter(requireActivity(), orderStatusList,this@OrdersByStatusFragment)

        rv_order_by_status.adapter = orderStatusListAdapter

    } else {

        rv_order_by_status.visibility = View.GONE
        tv_no_orders_by_status_found.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```

Comment: Just check for status inside the loop. F.e: 
`if(document.orderStatus == "Pending") `
   `//addTolist`

Comment: Your solution worked. If you add an answer then I'll mark that as the answer.

Comment: @AzimSalimov qayerliksiz

Comment: @sashabeliy Toshkent

Comment: ok, I will @Codist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you should just check for status inside the loop.
F.e:

```
if(document.orderStatus == "Pending")  
  //addTolist
```